How to recreate and adjust the auto-scale button in pyqtgraph
I want to have the auto-scale button that is normally in the bottom left hand corner and OUTSIDE of each subplot for a pyqtgraph, but rather than auto-scaling to fit the data, scale to a specific coordinate. The issue is that if I add a button to each subplot, it uses the location x and y axis scale. I want it so that it is always in the bottom left hand corner of each subplot no matter the values (like the default A button). Affectively, I want the auto-scale button to show even more area on the x and y axes than all the data points
I tried using:
auto_button = QPushButton(f"Auto {i+1}")
            auto_button.setFixedSize(20, 10)
            auto_button.clicked.connect(lambda _, p=plot, xmin=self.xdata[i][0], xmax=self.xdata[i][-1],ymin=self.ylim[i][0], ymax=self.ylim[i][1]: self.set_custom_range(p, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))
            
proxy = QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget()
            proxy.setWidget(auto_button)
            proxy.setPos(10,10)
            plot.addItem(proxy)

but the size and position of that button will be local to the x axis and INSIDE the plot.
Is there a way I can have it so that it is exactly where the 'A' button is?
My code:
import sys
import random
import time
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

class StockPriceUpdater(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe, stock_name, prices):
        super().__init__()
        self.pipe = pipe
        self.stock_name = stock_name
        self.prices = prices

    def run(self):
        while True:
            new_price = self.prices[-1] + random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5)
            self.prices = np.append(self.prices, new_price)
            self.pipe.send((self.stock_name, self.prices.copy()))
            time.sleep(10)

def autoBtnClicked2(self):
        print('We have a click')
        if self.autoBtn.mode == 'auto':
            print('auto_button true')
            # Changed this : self.enableAutoRange()
            x, y = self.curves[0].getOriginalDataset()
            self.vb.setRange(
                xRange=[x[0]-20, 2*x[-1]],
                yRange=[y[0], y[-1]]
            )
            # End of change
            self.autoBtn.hide()         
        else:
            print('auto_button false')

            self.disableAutoRange()

class StockPriceApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setup_multiprocessing()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Stock Prices')
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        self.graph_layout = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.graph_layout)

        self.plots = []
        self.curves = []
        self.xdata = [np.arange(10)] * 4
        
        self.ylim = {}
        self.xlim = {}
        self.ini_ydata = {}
        
        for i in range(4):
            plot = self.graph_layout.addPlot(row=i//2, col=i%2, title=f'Stock {i+1}')
            prices = 10 + np.cumsum(np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, 10))
            
            plot.autoBtnClicked = autoBtnClicked2     # The adjustment
            
            self.update_axis_limits(plot, i, self.xdata[i], prices)
            self.ini_ydata[i] = prices
            curve = plot.plot(self.xdata[i], prices, pen='y')

            self.plots.append(plot)
            self.curves.append(curve)
            
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plots)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def position_button(self, view_box, proxy):
        rect = view_box.sceneBoundingRect()
        proxy.setPos(rect.left() + 10, rect.bottom() - 40)  

    def setup_multiprocessing(self):
        self.pipes = {}
        self.processes = {}
        for i in range(4):
            stock_name = f'Stock{i+1}'
            parent_pipe, child_pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()
            self.pipes[stock_name] = parent_pipe
            process = StockPriceUpdater(child_pipe, stock_name, self.ini_ydata[i])
            process.start()
            self.processes[stock_name] = process

    def update_plots(self):
        for i, (stock_name, pipe) in enumerate(self.pipes.items()):
            if pipe.poll():
                _, prices = pipe.recv()
                self.xdata[i] = np.append(self.xdata[i], self.xdata[i][-1] + 1)
                self.curves[i].setData(self.xdata[i], prices)
                self.update_axis_limits(self.plots[i], i, self.xdata[i], prices)

    def set_custom_range(self, plot, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max):
        plot.getViewBox().setRange(xRange=[x_min, x_max], yRange=[y_min, y_max])

    def update_axis_limits(self, plot, stock, xvals, yvals):
        xmin = xvals.min()
        xmax = xvals.max()
        offset = (xmax - xmin) / 3 
        xmax = xmax + offset
        
        if isinstance(yvals, list):
            yvals = np.array(yvals)
            
        ymin = yvals.min()
        ymax = yvals.max()
        offset = (ymax - ymin) / 10
        
        ymax = ymax + offset
        ymin = ymin - offset
        
        self.ylim[stock] = (ymin, ymax)
        self.xlim[stock] = (xmin, xmax)

        plot.getViewBox().setRange(xRange=[xmin, xmax], yRange=[ymin, ymax], padding=0)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        for process in self.processes.values():
            process.terminate()
        event.accept()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    stock_app = StockPriceApp()
    stock_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Can you also attach the observed and expected output?

The code should run as is. I am trying to recreate the functionality of the small A in bottom left corner that are in all the subplots, but with a slight change. My actual code is far more complicate, but this is a stripped down version.

You can change the functionality of that "A" button and customize it creating a new method and replacing the original one. This will not change the original package in other scrips or projects.
import pyqtgraph as pg

def autoBtnClicked2(self):
        if self.autoBtn.mode == 'auto':
            # Changed this : self.enableAutoRange()
            x, y = self.curves[0].getOriginalDataset()
            self.vb.setRange(
                xRange=[x[0]-5, x[-1]+5],
                yRange=[y[0]-2, y[-1]+2]
            )
            # End of change
            self.autoBtn.hide()         
        else:
            self.disableAutoRange()

pg.graphicsItems.PlotItem.PlotItem.autoBtnClicked = autoBtnClicked2


